# consolidate multiple time series

Tags: python, bigdata

I'm currently have a problem with interpreting the trend for 1000+ entries.

1. Each entry has varying amount of periods (30~50)
2. A scatterplot of the entries look like a giant blob all across the graph.
3. Most of the dots is at y=0. However, the data looks unkept.
4. I tried using a mean or median for each month and doing a regression. However, I don't think the result doesn't tell much.

Thus, do you think it'd be helpful if I divide the dataset into more specific category to isolate the data?

Comment: What type of data is it?

Comment: it's a csv. specifically, monthly rent over 5 year periods

Comment: The trend you're looking into, is it for on time monthly payments? Late payments? Or which?

Comment: on time montly payments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do time series analysis then you'll need of the three packages: [Pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas), [Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/), or [Statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/). It all comes down to personal opinion but I listed them in the order I believe is best.

Once you have chose one of the three you'll need to foucs on Ordinary Least Square method (OLS), Regressive Analysis, and Autoregressive Moving Average.

The method that you approach from the top ones is really based on the results you'll get.